# Send signal with a delay to my own process in C on linux (ubuntu)

Tags: c, linux, signals, ipc

My program get lots of signals in a second. Yet, I want to be able to perform some code every second. If I just do:

```
toSleep = ONESEC;
while (toSleep > 0)
    toSleep = sleep(toSleep);
```

The signals that the program gets cause this while loop to starve.

If there could be some way to send my own process a signal every second that would be perfect because that signal will wait in the signal queue to take place in it's turn.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a child send the signal.  A trivial example with no error checking (also, you should use sigaction instead of signal):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handle( int s ) { return; }
int main( void ) {
    if( fork()) {
        while( 1 ) {
            signal( SIGUSR1, handle );
            pause();
            printf( "Signal received\n" );
        }
    } else {
        while( 1 ) {
            sleep( 1 );
            kill( getppid(), SIGUSR1 );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, rather than sending a signal, you might consider having the child write into a pipe (or use `signalfd()` if that is available) and then block on a read.  It is sometimes significantly cleaner to avoid signals entirely.